# How can I get around UAC when using ReadDirectoryChanges?

Tags: windows, winapi, uac

I have an application that needs to monitor the primary drive for file changes via `ReadDirectoryChangesW`. However, when UAC is enabled, it doesn't work.

All of the Windows API calls succeed, but I'm not notified of any changes.

I can work around this by individually monitoring each directory in the root, but this is a problem, because it can potentially cause a blue screen if there are too many directories.

Is there an acceptable way to get around UAC and receive file change notifications on the entire primary drive?

The relevant `CreateFile` and `ReadDirectoryChangesW` is below. In the case where it doesn't work, `directory` is C:\. If I monitor any secondary drive (i.e. E:\, F:\, G:\) it works as expected. None of the calls return errors.

```
HANDLE fileHandle = CreateFileW(directory.c_str(), FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY, 
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 
    FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);

BOOL success = ReadDirectoryChangesW(fileHandle, watched.buffer.data(),
    watched.buffer.size(), TRUE, 
    FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE, 
    NULL, &watched.overlapped, NULL);
```

Interestingly, the .NET `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher` **does** work correctly, and it uses the exact same functions and parameters as I'm using, but it behaves correctly.

Comment: Does it work if the application is elevated?

Comment: No, it doesn't work when I run it as an administrator, nor can I give myself (as an administrator) the ability to write to files in the root of the primary volume.

Comment: How can you BlueScreen a computer from an unelevated user mode process ? You might make the user's face turn blue if you consume enough resources, though...

Comment: `ReadDirectoryChangesW` allocates a copy of the buffer it's given in system memory.

Comment: @dauphic: Harry's question was not whether you were logged in as administrator, but whether you ran elevated. Those things can occur together, but need not.

Comment: @dauphic: what bug check code do you get in the BSOD?

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: I meant both; I'm logged in as an administrator, have run it with elevated privileges via the shell, and have run it with elevated privileges via the manifest. There is no BSOD or error in general, it just doesn't return any changes. I don't want to monitor each directory in C: individually, as a work around, because of the _potential_ BSOD.

Comment: Just to clarify: if UAC is disabled, it *does* work?  What about if UAC is enabled but you are logged in with the built-in Administrator account, which doesn't get a split token?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: If UAC is disabled, it __does__ work. If UAC is enabled and I'm logged in as the built-in Administrator, it does not work. It doesn't explicitly fail, it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Have you tried using synchronous rather than asynchronous IO?  It's working for me, and that's the only obvious thing I'm doing differently.  (Email me if you want a complete copy of my test code.)

Comment: It __does__ work if I do it synchronously. However, I need it to be asynchronous because I'm watching multiple drives. :(

Comment: Still working for me, even using asynchronous IO.  Can you post (or email) complete test code?

Comment: Yes. I've found out that the first call to `ReadDirectoryChangesW` doesn't work, it had nothing to do with the primary drive. Maybe a race condition.

Comment: Turns out I was associating the first file handle with a NULL IOCP handle. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

First it is best for applications that use the `ReadDirectoryChangesW` API to run elevated make a manifest file for you app and set `requireAdministrator` as the `requestedExecutionLevel` level. Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) for reference.

Try removing `FILE_SHARE_WRITE` from the `CreateFile` call if you are using it.

Another option is to make your program run as a service, im not sure how applicable this is to your needs. You could post some code as to how you are getting the file handle and what are you passing to `ReadDirectoryChangesW`

Comment: Is there a difference between running the application as an administrator via 'Run as Administrator' and requesting elevated priveleges in the manifest? I've tried with and without `FILE_SHARE_WRITE`, it makes no difference. The two function calls have been added.

Comment: The manifest option makes sure that your application always run with adminstrative privs without the need for the user to run it as admin. you can also try removing the FILE_SHARE_DELETE form your CreateFile call

Comment: And it doesnt work on your C drive because its the system drive... It is probably best to run your app as a service if all other attempts fail

Comment: I changed the manifest to require administrator privileges and removed `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`. No change in behavior, it still doesn't receive changes on the system drive. At the moment, making it a service isn't possible.

Comment: Actually its highly recommended to make it as a service since you want to monitor the whole system drive....

Comment: It will be made one, but it can't be right now. There needs to be another way to accomplish this, because `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher` is working with the exact same parameters.

Comment: You can try removing the FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS since it Only overrides security checks when the process has  SE_BACKUP_NAME and SE_RESTORE_NAME and since your app doesnt have those and since there is no way for a desktop app to modify its previlages to add these, then there is no need to add it. But I really doubt that it will work.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with my `ReadDirectoryChangesW` or `CreateFileW` calls. I think there has to be something else I need to do. Like I said, C# succeeds with the __exact__ same parameters. The `CreateFile` call isn't valid without 'FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS`

Comment: As i said i didnt think it will work... So when passing the handle for C drive to the ReadDirectoryChangesW does it succeed and if not whats the error your getting from GetLastError

Comment: Yes, every winapi call succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some working test code, for future reference.

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    HANDLE filehandle;
    BYTE buffer[65536];
    DWORD dw;
    FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION * fni;
    OVERLAPPED overlapped = {0};

    overlapped.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (overlapped.hEvent == NULL)
    {
        printf("CreateEvent: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    filehandle = CreateFile(L"C:\\", 
        FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY, 
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, 
        NULL, 
        OPEN_EXISTING, 
        FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 
        NULL);

    if (filehandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("CreateFile: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    for (;;)
    {
        if (!ReadDirectoryChangesW(filehandle, buffer, sizeof(buffer),
            TRUE, 
            FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE, 
            NULL, &overlapped, NULL))
        {
            printf("ReadDirectoryChangesW: %u\n", GetLastError());
            return 1;
        }

        printf("Queued OK.\n");

        if (!GetOverlappedResult(filehandle, &overlapped, &dw, TRUE))
        {
            printf("GetOverlappedResult: %u\n", GetLastError());
            return 1;
        }

        printf("%u bytes read.\n", dw);

        fni = (FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION *)buffer;

        for (;;)
        {
            printf("Next entry offset = %u\n", fni->NextEntryOffset);
            printf("Action = %u\n", fni->Action);
            printf("File name = %.*ws\n", 
                                  fni->FileNameLength / 2, 
                                  fni->FileName);

            if (fni->NextEntryOffset == 0) break;

            fni = (FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION *)
                               (((BYTE *)fni) + fni->NextEntryOffset);
        }
    }

    printf("All done\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the privileges of your process yourself like this:

```
// enable the required privileges for this process

LPCTSTR arPrivelegeNames[] = {  SE_BACKUP_NAME,
                                SE_RESTORE_NAME,
                                SE_CHANGE_NOTIFY_NAME
                             };

for (int i=0; i<(sizeof(arPrivelegeNames)/sizeof(LPCTSTR)); ++i)
{
    CAutoGeneralHandle hToken;
    if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, hToken.GetPointer()))
    {
        TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp = { 1 };

        if (LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, arPrivelegeNames[i],  &tp.Privileges[0].Luid))
        {
            tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

            AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(tp), NULL, NULL);
        }
    }
}
```

This works also for non-privileged processes (a.k.a. normal user processes).

Comment: This is not necessary.  You don't need to have the SE_BACKUP_NAME privilege in order to use FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS to open a handle to a directory.