# Waiting for folder tree to finish copying

Tags: winapi, file-locking

I am about to design a win32 process that periodically polls the contents of a specific folder (let's call it "incoming") for the arrival of folders.

These new folders will be created occasionally by another process that copies a directory/folder tree from somewhere else into the the "incoming" folder. It may even be created by a user drag-dropping a folder in Windows/File Explorer.

When my process polls, it will notice the presence of a new folder and will delve several levels down in the folder tree and read the contents of some of files it finds there.

It is important that my process waits until the whole folder tree has finished copying before it attempts to read it, otherwise it may miss some files that have not been copied yet.

So is there a way for my process to be sure that the entire folder tree has been fully copied? For example, is there a lock or property that gets set on the top level folder until all lower level folders and files have finished copying?

Comment: No such lock. You could use file notification mechanism. You could cooperate with the other process. You could wait until all the expected files have arrived.

Comment: *the entire folder tree has been fully copied* - this is impossible by design. what is *fully copied* ? how many|which items will be copied ? this is unknown. as result we can not know when process of copy new items is "finished". say somebody can periodically add new items permanent. no "finish" at all

Comment: I was half-expecting this but thought I'd better check if there was a simple mechanism I didn't know about. I guess it'll be a case of checking the existence and size of the files I'm interested in, then wait and check again until there were no differences.

Comment: `ReadDirectoryChanges` will notify about changes. Example https://stackoverflow.com/a/10728486/4603670 - You could wait 1 or 2 seconds after receiving the first change notification, if there is nothing new then assume the user is finished with the file operation.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani "_wait 1 or 2 seconds_" ... smells "unreliable". What if the user presses the "pause" button in the explorer copy progress dialog or anything unexpected happens, like explorer asking to overwrite existing files?

Comment: @zett42 Yes it's unreliable. That's why I said *"assume it's finished after 1 or 2 seconds..."* - I made up the time frame "1 or 2 seconds"